# Creating a small scale computer model of star forming cloud

Tags: model, simulation, physics

I want to create a small scale computer model of a star forming cloud. Where a random amount of random sized,mass dust of different elements forming a cloud of said dust that would be drawn toward each other, spin and collide to finally gradually form a massive object or star.But other than implementing gravity and magnetism forces. I'm not sure what I going to need to learn in order to make it work. So what I need from you guys is some pointers on what I should go and document myself on to be able to bring this project to life. What laws of physics and their maths will be indispensable? What should I use to visually display it?. I was thinking of going at it with C++ but should I pick a different language?. Hoping this question isn't inappropriate.
Thanks

Comment: A. Simulating dust is different from simulating particles. B. How do you deal with boundaries?

Comment: By "particles" I mean small objects with sizes ranging from dust to meters wide rocks and having at least 4-5 different element composition to get different mass over size. And I'm not sure what you mean by boundaries? I'm assuming you are asking what happens if a "rock" gets ejected from the gravitational spin by colliding with another. It will drift away and be destroyed unless gravity can drag it back before that.

Comment: How much of the physics do you already know? What phenomena do you want to see emerging in the simulation? (And what does magnetism have to do with it?)